# Memory footprint of an unused allocatable array

Tags: arrays, memory-management, fortran

Let's assume we have an array of 10 000 derived types defined as :

```
TYPE type1
    integer :: i
    real, dimension(:), allocatable :: real_array
END TYPE1
```

and

```
type(type1), dimension(1000) :: big_array
```

Now, we have the following statements in the main program :

```
DO j=1,10
    allocate(big_array(j)%real_array(100))
END DO
```

From component 11 to component 1000 of `big_array`, the `real_array`  is allocatable but not allocated because I don't need it. (I take the first ten components just as example but it can be any subscript)

Is it a problem in term of memory usage/management/efficiency ? What is the memory footprint of an "unused/unallocated allocatable array" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a problem at all.

The allocatable array components `real_array` are stored completely separately at "random" locations in the memory.

In the `big_array` itself you have only some descriptors or pointers of these components and the size of the `big_array` itself is not too big. You probably should not be worried about a couple of kilobytes.

In terms of efficiency the problem could be (but doesn't have to) that the components are at random locations, but that will be the same no matter how big the `big_array` is.

Comment: If I understand correctly, by declaring an explicit-shape `big_array` of `type1`, I create 1000 pointers/descriptors of `real_array` (negligible kilobytes I agree but they ALL exist) but these pointers are not referenced except for the first ten which point to the allocated memory space specified by the `allocate` statement, am I correct ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, the descriptors are there, but they are marked as unallocated/not pointing anywhere.

Comment: Finally, to be more specific about the first part of your answer about the "random" storage, do you mean that each `real_array` has its components stored non-contiguously ? By declaring the explicit shape array `big_array`, does it have its components stored contiguously ?

Comment: Every `real_array` is itself contiguous, but each individual `big_array(j)%real_array` begins at a random location, so the whole collection of `real_array`s is not contiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Instances of a derived type have no storage association whatsoever, each occupying an unspecified storage unit that is different in each case. The Fortran standard allows a compiler to rearrange the components of a derived type in any convenient order in memory. However, you do have the ability force the derived type to be stored contiguously in memory, simply use the `sequence` keyword

```
module type_MyStorage

  implicit none
  private

  type, public :: MyStorage
     sequence
     integer  :: i=0
     real     :: a(0:999)
  end type MyStorage

end module type_MyStorage
```

There are many downsides to doing this. Should any other derived types appear in such a definition, they too must be sequence types, no type-bound procedures or `pointer` components are allowed.

Upshot, variables declared to be of sequence types without `allocatable` components can appear in `equivalence` statements and the dreaded `common` block.

```
program main

  use type_MyStorage, only: MyStorage

  implicit none

  type (MyStorage) :: foo, bar

  equivalence (foo, bar)

  foo%i = 42
  print *, bar%i

end program main
```